# Why is my api key null with ServiceStack ApiKeyAuthProvider?

Tags: servicestack

Here is my Auth config:

```
container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
new IAuthProvider[]
{
    new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings) 
}));
```

I then add a GlobalRequestFilter so I can check live vs test:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{
    var user = req.GetUser();
    var apikey = req.GetApiKey();
}
```

Both user and apikey are null.

I'm using the method of embedding the apikey as the username for Basic Authentication. I see the header in the request. Will that not work here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IRequest.GetUser()` is an extension method that returns the Windows Auth ASP.NET `IPrincipal` (i.e. if using `AspNetWindowsAuthProvider`), it's not related to ServiceStack Auth which is based on [User Sessions](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions).

But the ApiKey should be returned for API Key Auth Requests as seen in this [stand-alone API Key Auth integration test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/55f5383f89e1be214d96f3f5edcdd5d9617cd24a):

#### Minimal AppHost using OrmLite AuthRepository

```
class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
{
    public static ApiKey LastApiKey;

    public AppHost() : base(nameof(ApiKeyAuthTests), typeof(AppHost).GetAssembly()) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider);
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);

        container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(dbFactory));
        container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings) { RequireSecureConnection = false },
            })
        {
            IncludeRegistrationService = true,
        });

        GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
        {
            LastApiKey = req.GetApiKey();
        });
    }
}
```

#### Register new User and Access their API Keys

```
appHost = new AppHost()
    .Init()
    .Start("http://*:2337/");

var client = new JsonServiceClient(ListeningOn);
var response = client.Post(new Register
{
    UserName = Username,
    Password = Password,
    Email = "as@if{0}.com",
    DisplayName = "DisplayName",
    FirstName = "FirstName",
    LastName = "LastName",
});

userId = response.UserId;
apiRepo = (IManageApiKeys)appHost.Resolve<IAuthRepository>();
var apiKeys = apiRepo.GetUserApiKeys(userId);
liveKey = apiKeys.First(x => x.Environment == "live");
testKey = apiKeys.First(x => x.Environment == "test");
```

#### A Minimal Authenicated Service

```
public class RequiresAuth : IReturn<RequiresAuth>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Authenticate]
public class RequiresAuthService : Service
{
    public object Any(RequiresAuth request) => request;
}
```

#### Calling the Authenticated Service with an API Key

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(ListeningOn)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(liveKey.Id, ""),
};

var request = new RequiresAuth { Name = "foo" };
var response = client.Send(request);
Assert.That(response.Name, Is.EqualTo(request.Name));

Assert.That(AppHost.LastApiKey.Id, Is.EqualTo(liveKey.Id));
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I'm going to set up some tests to see if I can track down where I'm losing it. It might make sense to mention - the Authentication is working correctly, the only problem is trying to get the key from the incoming request. Am I trying to catch it at the wrong place in the pipeline?

Comment: Scratch that - I'm sorry to have wasted your time. Upon rebuilding today and debugging, magically, the value is no longer null and everything is working.